# video upload in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to upload video.I have write following code.

In **Model**

```
[['videoFile'], 'file','extensions' => 'mp4','maxFiles' => 1],
```

In **View**,

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'videoFile')->fileInput()->label(false) ?>
```

In **controller**,

```
$model->videoFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'videoFile');
            print_r($model->videoFile);exit;
```

But continuously facing following **problem**

> Array ( [0] => yii\web\UploadedFile Object ( [name] =>
>   SampleVideo_1280x720_2mb.mp4 [tempName] => [type] => [size] => 0
>   [error] => 1 ) )

Here **tempName** is empty and [error] => 1.

Any idea what I am doing wrong.
How can we show uploadFile error here.

Thanks

Comment: You need to change `php.ini` find `MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE` and you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

temppath(server tempary store path) not found that why you get error

like xampp server path store (C:\xampp\tmp) this location store tempary file

Comment: check apache/nginx configuration to see /tmp path

Comment: I have use same code for multiple image upload and its working fine but stuck with upload video

Comment: video validation not availble in yii2

Answer (score -1):

Try to uplaod by this way :

```
if(isset($_FILES['videoFile']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['videoFile']['tmp_name'] != null)
{
  $file = $_FILES;
  $model->videoFile = "YourPath/".$file['videoFile']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file($file['videoFile']['tmp_name'],"YourPath/".$model->videoFile);
}
```